# How do I print different form of numbers?

Tags: c++

[Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmmSw.png)I am new to C++ and I have small problem.
I want to make program where I scan two numbers and get their sum:
e.g.
Input: 1 2
Output: 3

Input. 1.1 2.2
Output: 3.3

I struggle with switching between float or int.
If I scan for int(%d) I can't get float variable, but if I scanf float then as 1st output I get 3.00 instead of 3.
By this I want to achieve that decimal number will be in decimal form and number like 3 in its form without decimal zeros.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, what books or resources to learn C++ are you using? No [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) should tell you to use `scanf`. Secondly, why not read only floating point numbers? Integers are just floating-point values without decimals.

Comment: "If I scan for int(%d) I can't get float variable, but if I scanf float then as 1st output I get 3.00 instead of 3." Please show a [mre] which demonstrates that.

Comment: I uploaded a picture. The thing is that if I input 1 and 2 I get 3.00 but I want to get 3 without decimal. But, if I type 1.1 and 2.2 I want to get 3.3. I want to combine this.

Comment: Don't post images of text, least of all code. Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also, there's nothing C++ specific in the code, it could be all plain C.

Comment: @RenatoRak What if the input is 1.1 and 3 , then what should be the output? Should it be 3.1 or 3 ? That is how will you decide whether the output should be float or int?

Comment: I'll guess you live in Brazil, and therefore have to type "1,1" instead of "1.1"

Answer (score 1):

You can read the two numbers with `std::cin`, then output the sum with `std::cout`.

You can use `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` to control the format of the output. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vMjMG887o)

```cpp
#include <iomanip>  // setprecision
#include <ios>  // fixed
#include <iostream>  // cin, cout

int main()
{
    double d1{0.0};
    double d2{0.0};
    std::cin >> d1 >> d2;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << d1 << " + " << d2 << " = " << d1 + d2 << "\n";
}
```

If you want to output decimals only when needed, just don't use `fixed` and `precision`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bb5TzbEPe)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cin, cout

int main()
{
    double d1{0.0};
    double d2{0.0};
    std::cin >> d1 >> d2;
    std::cout << d1 << " + " << d2 << " = " << d1 + d2 << "\n";

    double d3{0.0};
    double d4{0.0};
    std::cin >> d3 >> d4;
    std::cout << d3 << " + " << d4 << " = " << d3 + d4 << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scan a `std::string`, check whether there is a dot in it using `std::find` and converting to an int (`std::stoi`) or a float (`std::stof`) accordingly. By the way, in C++, you should use `std::cin` instead of `scanf`.